# How to implement a c++11 move function for a user-defined class?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics

I have a user-defined class (tree structure) with implemented move semantics, and a `swap` function. I would like to implement a `move` function the proper way, working as standard std::move implementation.

In the tree node class, each child node has a `parent` pointer, pointing to the parent node. This means that for move operations, all children have to reparented (and there may be many children)

This means that use of `swap` for moving is not optimal, as children of both lists have to be reparented after being swapped. So I would like to implement a `move` function which clears the moved-from tree.

The declaration of std::move implementations is somewhat complicated, they use a `std::remove_reference<T>::type&&` return type. Do I need this?

Comment: This is very unclear. The single-argument `std::move` is just a cast, there's no need to implement anything on your part. And an internal `swap` usually works on lvalue references anyway.

Comment: `remove_reference` is quite trivial. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_reference

Comment: You can simplify the definition a bit if your compiler supports `decltype(auto)` (a C++14 feature AFAIK) (see approx 6.5 minutes into [this talk by Scott Meyers](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/GoingNative/2013/An-Effective-Cpp11-14-Sampler))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to write a specialisation of std::move.

If you write a correct move constructor and move assignment operator, std::move will work on your class.

example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct Thing {
    Thing()
    : _data(new int[100])
    {
        cout << "default construct\n";

    }

    // Copy operator
    Thing(const Thing& other)
    : _data(new int[100])
    {
        cout << "copy constructor\n";
        memcpy(_data, other._data, sizeof(int) * 100);
    }

    // Move constructor
    Thing(Thing&& other) noexcept
    : _data(other._data)
    {
        cout << "move constructor\n";
        other._data = nullptr;
    }

    // assignment operator
    Thing& operator=(const Thing& rhs) {
        cout << "copy operator\n";
        if (&rhs != this) {
            Thing tmp(rhs);
            std::swap(*this, tmp);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    // move assignment operator
    Thing& operator=(Thing&& rhs) noexcept {
        cout << "move operator\n";
        std::swap(_data, rhs._data);
        return *this;
    }


    // destructor necessary since we are working in dangerous new/delete territory
    ~Thing() noexcept {
        cout << "destructor " << (_data ? "object has data" : "object is empty") << "\n";

        delete[] _data;
    }
private:
    int* _data;
};
int main()
{
    cout << "constructing a\n";
    Thing a;

    cout << "constructing b with copy of a\n";
    Thing b(a);

    cout << "moving a to newly constructed c\n";
    Thing c(std::move(a));

    cout << "moving c back to a\n";
    a = std::move(c);

    cout << "create a new d\n";
    Thing d;
    cout << "replace d with a copy of a\n";
    d = a;

    return 0;
}
```

Program's output:

```
constructing a
default construct
constructing b with copy of a
copy constructor
moving a to newly constructed c
move constructor
moving c back to a
move operator
create a new d
default construct
replace d with a copy of a
copy operator
copy constructor
move constructor
move operator
move operator
destructor object is empty
destructor object has data
destructor object has data
destructor object is empty
destructor object has data
destructor object has data
```

Comment: I was starting from the fact that std::move does effectively swap on standard containers, which I don't want.

So std::move will swap only if my move ctor/assignment do swap, and move if they move? Makes sense

Comment: std::move simply converts an object reference into an R-value reference, allowing and object's move constructor or move operator to be selected.

I'll write a little example for you.

Comment: There you go. example provided. Compile it and single step though it.

Comment: Don't forget `noexcept`.  Many standard libraries will degenerate into safer copy semantics if they can't guarantee that moves are no-throw.

Comment: It's been healthy to write a full implementation of a pointer-controlling class from scratch - it's underlined once again why we should not do it since it's so difficult to get right without errors, while `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` do everything you'd ever want to do with a pointer perfectly and safely.

Answer (score 2):

To write move semantics is to write move constructor/move assignment, but not to implement move function. As result, you maybe move the root of the another tree in move ctor/assignment.

```
class binary_tree_node {};

class binary_tree
{
public:
    binary_tree() : root(nullptr) {}

    binary_tree(binary_tree &&rhs)
        : root(rhs.root)
    {
        rhs.root = nullptr;
    }

    binary_tree& operator=(binary_tree rhs)
    {
        swap(rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    void swap(binary_tree &rhs)
    {
        std::swap(root, rhs.root);
    }

private:
    binary_tree_node *root;
};

int main()
{
    binary_tree tree1;
    binary_tree tree2 = std::move(tree1);

    return 0;
}
```